# Aging: Only humans have grey hair?

Tags: human-biology, senescence, hair

I am not sure if I ever saw a monkey or a bird age and lose hair pigment as it grows. It maybe due to my lack of information. But it appears to be a general presumption that only humans age and lose hair pigment (hence developing grey hair).

If this is true, then I am curious why only humans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is restricted to humans. Dogs lose hair pigment as well, usually around the [muzzle](https://books.google.it/books?hl=it&lr=&id=FVVMDwAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PT13&dq=aging%20dog%20gray%20hair&ots=IPlP_Hyhq_&sig=ZPFTaLi5VCKEb2bYmqD9RlUaxm0&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=gray&f=false). 
This [work](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168159111002668?casa_token=I0KDdKV3ItcAAAAA:uXX1uECbbTtwi8em9lGqZ8yO7ZT4cPXqbJV_hS8loM7RWwmjc-A9K4rA1MoWsB1rGnjvgxqm) used graying of hair to discriminate senior dogs.
I don't know which other mammals lose hair pigment, though, nor why.

Comment: We also see this in big apes.